# Error copying folder using scp

Tags: scp

I want to copy a folder from remote server. When I use this command to copy just a single file>

```
scp -P 11096 user@server:FullPathToFile WhereToSave
```

it works well, but when I use -r to copy the folder as:

```
scp -r 11096 user@server:FullPathToFile WhereToSave
```

it gives me an error:

```
cp: cannot stat '11096': No such file or directory
```

Any idea? Thanks for help!

Comment: isn't the 11096 port number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
scp -r -P 11096 user@server:FullPathToFile WhereToSave
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. Thanks!